# why does the counter not work after the break command?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for words. It breaks when the user types in a word for the second time. The code I've got below should be working fine, but for some reason, the counter stops counting after one try. I have no idea why, could someone please help? It would be appreciated.

```
count = 0

while True:
    my_word = input("Word: ")
    if my_word == my_word in my_word:
        count += 1
        print(f"You typed in", (count), "different words")
        break
```

Comment: What do you believe `my_word == my_word in my_word` does exactly?

Comment: In short, the `my_word == my_word in my_word` evaluates to `True`, therefore the `break` statement is executed in the first loop.  What do you intend this line to mean / do?

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten your code:

```py
count = 0
words = []

while True:
    my_word = input("Word: ")
    if my_word in words:
        print(f"You typed in ", count, " different words")
        break
    count += 1
    words.append(my_word)
```

I have created a list `words` which will hold all words user inputs.

Whith each iteration we are checking if my_word is already inputed. If it is we are printing an output and ending a program.

If it isn't we are incrementing `count` (adding 1 to `count`) and appending (adding value to the end of the list) `my_word` to `words`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was drafted to help explain:

- The primary issue with the original code and *why* it was an issue.
- Provide a working example of the code.

---

### The issue:

The primary issue with the original code is this line, which will *always* evaluate to `True`; thus breaking the loop on first entry.

```
if my_word == my_word in my_word  # --> True
```

This line uses a technique called ['operator chaining'](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) which essentially evaluates the above expression as follows; notice the `and`.

```
if my_word == my_word and my_word in my_word
```

Per the documentation:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

#### Bytecode:

I realise this *might* be above your current Python understanding, but have included it for completeness and possible future reference.

If you refer to the bytecode, you'll see this is exactly what's happening; with the second `my_word` only being evaluated once - note the `DUP_TOP` and `ROT_THREE` instructions.

```
>>> word = 'WORD'
>>> dis('word == word in word')

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (word)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (word)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_NAME                0 (word)
             14 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

### Working example:

In the example below, the user is continuously prompted for a word, with each new word being added to the `words` list. Once a word is found in the list of words, a notification is printed and the loop is exited.

```
count = 0
words = []

while True:
    my_word = input("Type a word: ")
    if my_word in words:
        print(f'Duplicate found, exiting. There are {len(words)} different words.')
        break
    words.append(my_word)
```

Output:

```
Type a word: bob
Type a word: sue
Type a word: stan
Type a word: bob
Duplicate found, exiting. There are 3 different words.
```